# How to increase pytorch timeout?

Tags: pytorch

I'm training ML model with yolov5 this is my command -

```
python3 -m torch.distributed.run --nproc_per_node 2 train.py --batch 100 --epochs 1000 --data /home/username/Documents/folder_name/numbers.yaml --weights yolov5s.pt --device 0,1 --hyp data/hyps/hyp.scratch-high.yaml --name folder_name --patience 0
```

It will cut out after 30min, because of the default pytorch timeout 1800s. How can I increase it?

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributed.html#torch.distributed.init_process_group

Thanks